# Script for Executing a Scheduled Post

Tags: php, post, cron, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

I want to create a feature on my website that allows users to schedule a post at a specific time. The posts will be placed in a queue and then posted at the specified time. What is the proper method for handling this? Do I need to create a separate cron job for each individual scheduled post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically this is done with a single cron job acting as "trigger". That trigger (a php script) checks the list of pending jobs in the database and executes one or more.

It might spawn sub requests for each job to improve robustness, but this adds load to the system.

It is important to mark started jobs inside the database so that in case of concurrent trigger processes (whyever, for example system load), a single job is not started *twice*. This is especially true for jobs that crash...

You might also want to implementing a locking strategy, so that only one single concurrent trigger request is possible.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply. So does that mean I have to run the cron job every 1 minute to check for the database for any posts in the queue?

Comment: Yep, that is the typical approach. That cronjob either uses `wget` or `curl` to make an http request to the local http server, or you use the cli version of php.

Comment: Ok thanks. I would upvote your answer but don't have atleast 15 points yet so I am not allowed to, sorry.

Comment: All fine, this place is not about some score for me :-)